# how can i set attributes of NSFontPanel?

Tags: objective-c, nsfont, nsfontmanager, nsfontpanel

How can i set font attributes of `NSFontPanel`, like color, bold etc ?

Answer (score 0):

Colors are actually not in the font panel, are they? The font can be changed with this method:

```
- (void)setPanelFont:(NSFont *)aFont isMultiple:(BOOL)flag
```

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFontPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000384-setPanelFont_isMultiple_).

Comment: Yeah.NSColorPanel is different..I am saying that I have option to change color of font in NSFontPanel.

Comment: Yep. But changing this heavily depends on the context you're in. You need to concretize your question then...